Structuring Store for IAP Swift to handle empty Products array returned by SKProductsRequest
I have an app which provides In App Purchase and I use this Store class to facilitate it. I recently noticed several crashes and looking at the crash indicated that the function productsRequest was causing this due to an index out of bounds error (see screenshot - also note that I couldn't work out how to go from the view in the screenshot directly to the offending code?). As a quick fix I added the guard statement which just checks in the array of returned products is empty and if so exits, but it's not ideal.
Questions:
1, What type of responses can we expect to see with an empty products array that could have triggered this crash? (I haven't been able to repro it, in fact I always get the product returned twice)
2, What would be a better way to handle the types of responses we can expect rather than this pretty hacky check/exit logic?
import Foundation
import StoreKit

let PRODUCT_ID = MY_PRODUCT_ID
protocol ClassStoreDelegate: AnyObject {
    func storeUpdateReceived(store: Store)
}

class Store: NSObject, SKProductsRequestDelegate, SKPaymentTransactionObserver {
    // Properties
    weak var delegate: ClassStoreDelegate?
    var list = [SKProduct]()
    var p = SKProduct()
    var defaults = UserDefaults.standard // Where we save whether the user is pro
    var localTitle: String?
    var localDescription: String?
    var localPrice: String?
    var presentAlert = false
    var alertTitle = "Alert"
    var alertMessage = "Unfortunately something went wrong"
    
    // Methods
    // Calling the delegate method
    func storeUpdate() {
        delegate?.storeUpdateReceived(store: self)
    }
    
    // Buy the product
    func buy() {
        for product in list {
            let prodID = product.productIdentifier
            if(prodID == PRODUCT_ID) {
                p = product
                buyProduct()
            }
        }
    }
    
    // Restore products
    func restore() {
        SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)
        SKPaymentQueue.default().restoreCompletedTransactions()
    }
    
    
    func getProducts() {
        if(SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments()) {
            let productID: NSSet = NSSet(objects: PRODUCT_ID)
            let request: SKProductsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productID as! Set<String>)
            request.delegate = self
            request.start()
        } else {
            alertTitle = "Something went wrong"
            alertMessage = "Your phone does not appear to be set up for making purchases"
            presentAlert = true
            delegate?.storeUpdateReceived(store: self)
            
        }
    }
    
    func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {
        let myProduct = response.products
        // Check if the array is empty
            guard !myProduct.isEmpty else {
                // Handle the case where the array is empty, maybe log an error or perform some other action
                return
            }
        
        for product in myProduct {
            list.append(product)
        }
    
        // Update labels
        localTitle = list[0].localizedTitle
        localDescription = list[0].localizedDescription
        
        // Format the price and display
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.locale = Locale.current
        formatter.numberStyle = .currency
        if let formattedPrice = formatter.string(from: list[0].price){
            localPrice = ("Upgrade: \(formattedPrice)")
            delegate?.storeUpdateReceived(store: self)
        }
    }
    
    func paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue) {
        let transactionsArray = queue.transactions
        if (transactionsArray.isEmpty) {
            alertTitle = "Something went wrong"
            alertMessage = "We weren't able to find any previous purchases for your account"
            presentAlert = true
            delegate?.storeUpdateReceived(store: self)
        }
        else {
            for transaction in transactionsArray {
                let t: SKPaymentTransaction = transaction
                let prodID = t.payment.productIdentifier as String
                
                switch prodID {
                case PRODUCT_ID:
                    defaults.set(true, forKey: "pro")
                    pro = true
                    alertTitle = "Complete"
                    alertMessage = "Your purchase has been restored"
                    presentAlert = true
                    delegate?.storeUpdateReceived(store: self)
                default:
                    alertTitle = "Something went wrong"
                    alertMessage = "We weren't able to find the correct product"
                    presentAlert = true
                    delegate?.storeUpdateReceived(store: self)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func buyProduct() {
        let pay = SKPayment(product: p)
        SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)
        SKPaymentQueue.default().add(pay as SKPayment)
    }
    
    func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
        for transaction: AnyObject in transactions {
            let trans = transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction
            
            switch trans.transactionState {
            case .purchased:
                let prodID = p.productIdentifier
                switch prodID {
                case MY_PRODUCT_ID:
                    defaults.set(true, forKey: "pro") // Write pro to disk
                    pro = true
                    alertTitle = "Complete"
                    alertMessage = "Pro version unlocked, you now have full access to all content. Please leave a review in the AppStore when prompted!"
                    presentAlert = true
                    delegate?.storeUpdateReceived(store: self)
                default:
                    alertTitle = "Something went wrong"
                    alertMessage = "We weren't able to locate the correct product"
                    presentAlert = true
                    delegate?.storeUpdateReceived(store: self)
                }
                queue.finishTransaction(trans)
                break
            case .failed:
                alertTitle = "Something went wrong"
                alertMessage = "Unfortunately the purchase failed"
                presentAlert = true
                delegate?.storeUpdateReceived(store: self)
                queue.finishTransaction(trans)
                break
            case .restored:
                SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction)
                queue.finishTransaction(trans)
                break
            default:
                break
            }
        }
    }
    
}



What you have looks correct; you just need to do what you say in the comments; provide some feedback to the user that purchasing isn't available. It could be that they have no network or are in a region where in app purchases are not available. Also, storing your "pro" purchase in user defaults isn't very secure. Keychain is a better alternative.

Oh that's interesting. I didn't realise that this function would get a callback if they didn't have network.
